# Deleting S3 files with a given prefix only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

We have a bucket with more than 500,000 objects in it.

I'm assigned a job where I've to delete files which have a specific prefix. There are around 300,000 files with the given prefix in the bucket.

**For eg**
If there are 3 files

```
abc_1file.txt
abc_2file.txt
abc_1newfile.txt
```

I've to delete the files with abc_1 prefix only.
I didn't find much in AWS documentation related to this.

Any suggestions on how can I automate this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `aws s3 rm` command using the `--include` and `--exclude` parameters to specify a pattern for the files you'd like to delete.

So in your case, the command would be:

`aws s3 rm s3://bucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "abc_1*"`

which will delete all files that match the "abc_1*" pattern in the bucket.

Make sure to verify what it is being deleted before actually running the above command using the dry run flag, e.g. `aws s3 rm --dryrun s3://bucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "abc_1*"`

The behavior of these parameters is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

These instructions assume you have downloaded, installed and configured the [AWS CLI tools](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Comment: Important note: Order of operations matters! The same exact command can fail if you do include first and exclude second.

Comment: Excellent, but make sure to first take a look at what it would delete with `--dryrun`!

Comment: any idea how to do it with python boto3?

Comment: For s3cmd, the dry run flag is `--dry-run` - https://s3tools.org/usage.

Answer (score 23):

As a complement to @sippybear's excellent answer, I would recommend the following, if somebody has a bucket with a trillion objects and the pattern of the files one wants to delete includes "parent directories", e.g. `'my/path/to/topdir/abc_1*'`:

```
aws s3 rm --dryrun --recursive --exclude '*' --include 'abc_1*' s3://mybucket/my/path/to/topdir/
```

### Why?

1. this will restrict the search of objects to delete to the parent directory, thus considerably speeding up the operation;
2. really, do yourself a favor and start with `--dryrun`, even if you promptly interrupt it (`ctrl-C`); typos and other accidents happen and errors when deleting large number of files in a bucket can be very regrettable (even if you have proper backups)...

Once you're happy with what you see is about to be deleted, then remove the `--dryrun`.